# Time Required by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve the problem on this link using python:

```
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/tds-and-his-breakup/
```

I solved using two approach:

## 1

```
n = int(input())
min_skill = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    if int(input()) >= min_skill:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

## 2

```
n = int(input())
min_skill = int(input())
list_skill = []

for i in range(n):
    temp = int(input())
    list_skill.append(temp)

for skill in list_skill:
    if skill >= min_skill:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Why is the time and memory required by first approach is greater than the second one, although the second one is using a list to store the inputs as well as it iterates over the inputs twice?

Comment: Are you using the built in time/memory result on hacker earth to judge which one is faster/uses less memory?

Comment: I don't know enough to know why this matters, but I believe the reason that the second version is faster is that all the `input` calls are together and all the `print` calls are together, whereas in the first version the `input` and `print` calls are interleaved.

Comment: It could be the std out buffer waiting to clear and interfering with the std in while doing it?

Comment: Someone had the same question on this https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/21344175/ submission. One answer is "The list is stored in the secondary memory which doesn't affect cache/primary memory size. whereas reading and manipulating the incoming data simultaneously uses cache/primary memory only . Here the size of cache/primary memory is counted. correct me if I am wrong." I am not familiar enough with python memory to say if this is correct or not.